# az login using managed identity fails in az pipeline

Tags: azure

When I run the pipeline on AKS and run az login --identity it gives me an error as below. What should I do to fix this issue.
AzureResponseError: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly. Get Token request returned http error: 400, reason: Bad Request

Comment: Can you specify a bit more? Using Azure Devops release pipeline? with powershell?

Comment: Using like this, - bash: |
    az login  --identity                in yaml pipeline.

Comment: hosted agents or build machine?

Comment: Maybe this can help out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-cli